# Authentification in Laravel and React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, api, authentication

i'm having a problem to create authentification with laravel in the backend and react in the front end
here is my Controller code

```
public function register (Request $request){
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|max:255|confirmed',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => $validator->errors(),
            ], 422);
        }

        // Create a new user
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Registration successful!',
        ], 200);
}
```

and here is my react component

```
type here
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Register() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordConfirmation, setPasswordConfirmation] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          password_confirmation: passwordConfirmation,
        }),
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setSuccessMessage(responseData.message);
        setErrorMessage('');
      } else {
        setErrorMessage(responseData.errors.email[0]);
        setSuccessMessage('');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.message);
      setSuccessMessage('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {successMessage && <p>{successMessage}</p>}
      {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" id="password-confirmation" onChange={(event) => setPasswordConfirmation(event.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i tried it with axios too

there is my route in web.php

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('home');
})->where('any','.*');
```

and there is my route in api.php

```
Route::post('register',[AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

i excpected data go to the database but nothing happens just errors

Comment: What errors did you get??

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).